# The android studio terminal doesn't take my commands

Tags: android-studio, flutter, terminal, sdk

I'm trying to update the flutter SDK, but the terminal doesn't recognize the command.

```
 flutter upgrade
'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to export flutter to path for linux you can do something like this `export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"`

windows

If you wish to run Flutter commands in the regular Windows console, take these steps to add Flutter to the PATH environment variable:

From the Start search bar, enter `env` and select Edit environment variables for your account.
    Under User variables check if there is an entry called Path:
        If the entry exists, append the full path to `flutter\bin` using ; as a separator from existing values.
        If the entry doesn’t exist, create a new user variable named Path with the full path to flutter\bin as its value.

Note that you have to close and reopen any existing console windows for these changes to take effect

.
this should work...if on linux run the export path command in you android studio terminal window.

read more from [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)